# Check validity of matrix saved in txt file

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

I have a function that checks the validity of the matrix represented in the text file.
File should look like this:

```
3 5
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
7 6 4 3 2
```

The first line must contain dimensions of the matrix. Of course, every row must contain the same number of elements and all elements must be digits. Also, given dimensions must correspond to the given matrix. I've implemented a very ugly solution but I'd like to improve it.

```
int rowc, colc;
char row[MAXSIZE], digit;
char* pch;
int rlength, prev_rlenght;

FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    msg_print(file_nf);
    return inv_map;
}
for(int i = 0; fgets(row, MAXSIZE, fp); i++){
    if(i == 0){
        pch = strtok(row, " ");
        for(int i = 0; pch != NULL; i++){
            pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
            if(i > 2){
                return inv_map;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(i == 1){
        rlength = strcspn(row, "\n");
        continue;
    }
    else if(i > 1){
        prev_rlenght = rlength;
        rlength = strcspn(row, "\n");
        if(prev_rlenght != rlength){
            return inv_map;
        }
    }
    else
        continue;
}
rewind(fp);
//check dimensions
fscanf(fp, "%d", &rowc);
fscanf(fp, "%d", &colc);
int i = 0;
while((digit = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    if(isdigit(digit))
        i++;
if(i != rowc * colc)
    return inv_map;
rewind(fp);
```

If you have any idea how I can elegantly rewrite it, please tell me. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: By *all elements must be digits*, do you mean all elements must be integers or all elements must be integers with a single digit?

Comment: I would `fgets` to read the complete lines. Then I would call a helper function which only parses one number. The function should return a result if the number was read successfully, if the end of string was reached or if an invalid character was detected. Then the code should look nicer.

Comment: elements must be integers with a single digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution with `strtol()`:

- the function reads the first line and parses the row and column counts
- then it enters a loop read one line at a time, assuming they have less than `MAXSIZE-1` characters
- for each line, it parses as many numbers as it can
- if there are less than `cols` numbers or less than `rows` lines, the file is rejected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// return 0 if matrix is OK, non zero for error
int check_matrix(FILE *fp) {
    char buf[MAXSIZE];
    int row, col, rows, cols;
    char *p1, *p2;

    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp))
        return 1;
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d%d", &rows, &cols) != 2)
        return 2;
    if (rows < 0 || cols < 0)
        return 3;
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp))
            return 4;
        for (p1 = buf, col = 0;; col++) {
            while (*p1 == ' ')
                p1++;
            if (*p1 == '\n')
                break;
            errno = 0;
            strtol(p1, &p2, 10);
            if (errno != 0 || p2 == p1)
                return 5;
            p1 = p2;
        }
        if (col != cols)
            return 6;
    }
    rewind(fp);
    return 0;
}
```